# Firebase db reference in nextjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I'm new to react and nextjs:

How can I share the firebase reference on the pages?
Do I need to declare the reference on each page (where I want to use it) with the config etc as I did on the index page?

```
try {    
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "############",
        authDomain: "###############",
        databaseURL: "#########",
        projectId: "############",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "########"
    })

} catch (err) {    
    if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
        console.error('Firebase initialization error', err.stack)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally either use a configured instance of firebase which is shared as a service.

```js
// services/firebase.js

import firebase from 'firebase';

var config = {
    apiKey: "############",
    authDomain: "###############",
    databaseURL: "#########",
    projectId: "############",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "########"
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export default firebase;
```

Then you can import this service and use it throughout your application:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import firebase from 'services/firebase';

export default class DynamicPage extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        image: PropTypes.string
    };

    static async getInitialProps() {
        const props = {};
        const dbRef = firebase.database;
        // load some data and pass it to props
        return props;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                // render the data
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```